# Connecting to AWS Elasticsearch instance using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, heroku, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have an Elasticsearch instance, hosted on AWS. I can connect from my terminal with Curl. I am now trying to use the python elasticsearch wrapper. I have:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

client = Elasticsearch(host='https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', port=9200)
```

and the query is:

```
data = client.search(index="mynewindex", body={"query": {"match": {"email": "gmail"}}})
    for hit in data:
        print(hit.email)
    print data
```

The full traceback, from heroku,  is:

```
2016-07-22T14:06:06.031347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=elastictest.herokuapp.com request_id=9a96d447-fe02-4670-bafe-efba842927f3 fwd="88.106.66.168" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=393ms status=500 bytes=456
2016-07-22T14:09:18.035805+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-22T14:09:18.035810+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-07-22T14:09:18.147278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-07-22T14:09:18.147920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-07-22T14:09:20.838784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn application:application --log-file=-`
2016-07-22T14:09:20.834521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-07-22T14:09:17.850918+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b7187d3 by hector@fastmail.se
2016-07-22T14:09:17.850993+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v21 created by hector@fastmail.se
2016-07-22T14:09:21.372589+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:21 +0000] [3] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2016-07-22T14:09:21.383946+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:21 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-07-22T14:09:21.367656+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:21 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2016-07-22T14:09:21.366309+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:21 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2016-07-22T14:09:22.286766+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-07-22T14:09:23.344822+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:23 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
2016-07-22T14:09:23.345481+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:23 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2016-07-22T14:09:23.351173+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:23 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2016-07-22T14:09:23.370580+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:23 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2016-07-22T14:09:23.345376+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:23 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:59867 (3)
2016-07-22T14:09:24.536725+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043240+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043239+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043241+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043233+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043238+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043236+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043235+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043214+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:39,041] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043241+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043242+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043242+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043243+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043243+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/application.py", line 23, in index
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043246+00:00 app[web.1]:     return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043245+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043246+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 548, in search
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043247+00:00 app[web.1]:     doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043250+00:00 app[web.1]:     status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043250+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 105, in perform_request
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043244+00:00 app[web.1]:     data = client.search(index="mynewindex", body={"query": {"match": {"email": "gmail"}}})
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043251+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043249+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 329, in perform_request
2016-07-22T14:09:39.043253+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f185a94d8d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f185a94d8d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692817+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692816+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692795+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-22 14:09:42,691] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692820+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692819+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692819+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692827+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 329, in perform_request
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692828+00:00 app[web.1]:     status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692828+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 105, in perform_request
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692829+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692831+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f185a946d10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f185a946d10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692821+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692821+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692822+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692823+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/application.py", line 23, in index
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692823+00:00 app[web.1]:     data = client.search(index="mynewindex", body={"query": {"match": {"email": "gmail"}}})
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692824+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692814+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692818+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692815+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692825+00:00 app[web.1]:     return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692826+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 548, in search
2016-07-22T14:09:42.692826+00:00 app[web.1]:     doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
2016-07-22T14:09:42.685540+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=elastictest.herokuapp.com request_id=87ae9ec2-edb6-4e58-b9d6-89709b883091 fwd="88.106.66.168" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=456
```

I assume the error is with the "connection string" because the principal error appears to be `ConnectionError`

So two questions:

1) How can I connect correctly? Inbound security rules are currently configured to accept all incoming traffic

2) Is there an error in the query code?

Many thanks as always.

Comment: Security setting for what port are set to 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: sorry that may be misleading, what I mean is that inbound rules accept all incoming traffic so,as far as I understand, that will not be the reason for the failed connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a small script in Python that will help in creating a connection with AWS Elasticsearch instance.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth


host = '' # For example, my-test-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
region = '' # e.g. us-west-1

service = 'es'

credentials = {
    'access_key': '',
    'secret_key': ''
}

awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials['access_key'], credentials['secret_key'], region, service)

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)

print(es.info())
```

Reference: [AWS Elasticsearch Signing Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-python)

Answer (score 22):

This is the correct way to connect to elasticsearch server using python:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['IP:PORT',])
```

Elasticsearch's constructor **doesn't have** the `host` nor the `port` parameters. The first parameter should be a list, where each item in the list can be either a string representing the host:

```
'schema://ip:port'
```

Or a dictionary with extended parameters regarding that host

```
{'host': 'ip/hostname', 'port': 443, 'url_prefix': 'es', 'use_ssl': True}
```

---

In your case you probably would like to use:

```
 client = Elasticsearch(['https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200'])
```

> The port is redundant since you are using the deafult one, so you can use remove it
>        `client = Elasticsearch(['https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com'])`

Comment: Thanks. I tried both IP and Url and neither works. In each case the response is connection refused. You can see above, in the question, that I tried that. Is the problem on the ec2 server?

Comment: @user1903663, there is no `host=` in Elasticsearch's constructor. I updated the answer to emphasize that.

Comment: The other option is that your server (heroku) is blocking your outgoing connections. Can you try to run `import urllib2; urllib2.urlopen('https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200')` from that server?

Comment: hang on a sec, I will give that a shot

Comment: check the python syntax :)

Comment: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118157/discussion-between-dekel-and-user1903663).

Comment: is the error on ec2 (unlikely as I can access with SSH) or elsewhere?

Comment: The critical bit for this was that the elasticsearch.yml network.host needed to be changed on the ec2 server. So:
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml then change the ip address and uncomment the line

Comment: I've got a similar issue however my elasticsearch is hosted on Amazon Elastic Service, `Elasticsearch([endpoint])` doesn't seem to work with any variation of port (no port, 443 or 9200) and instead of erroring it just freezes my IDE (pycharm) @Dekel

Comment: Do you have the relevant port open in AWS?

Comment: Remove `https://`

`client = Elasticsearch([ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200'])`

Answer (score 7):

```
host = 'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' #without 'https'
YOUR_ACCESS_KEY = ''
YOUR_SECRET_KEY = ''
REGION = 'us-west-2' #change to your region
awsauth = AWS4Auth(YOUR_ACCESS_KEY, YOUR_SECRET_KEY, REGION, 'es')

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)
print(es.info())
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Instance Roles, if running on an ECS cluster?

Comment: @Jhirschibar Perhaps try with boto3 `credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()` - [more detailed example from AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-python)