# Can't create a working elasticsearch-py instance

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I've got an Amazon ElasticSearch Service running and I can connect fine using a curl/postman, but when I try to create a elasticsearch-py instance my ide hangs indefinitely.

```
endpoints = ['http://XXX.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com',
             'http://XXX.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443',
             'http://XXX.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:9200']

for endpoint in endpoints:
    try:
        es = Elasticsearch(endpoint)
        print es.count('analytics_v4')
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        print endpoint + " didn't work"
```

This is my current test set up, my IDE (pycharm) completely stops at this point and I need to end the run to be able to try again, I've tried each endpoint individually and none of them work.

My access policy is :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:MYIDdomain/analytics/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "MYIP"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting an error for :433 of : 
`ConnectionError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='MYID.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /analytics_v4/_count (Caused by <class 'httplib.BadStatusLine'>: '')) caused by: MaxRetryError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='MYID.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /analytics_v4/_count (Caused by <class 'httplib.BadStatusLine'>: ''))`

Comment: Any reason you're passing a one element list to `Elasticsearch([endpoint])` and not just the endpoint... `Elasticsearch(endpoint)` ?

Comment: @JonClements I was trying to stick to something like the solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528839/connecting-to-aws-elasticsearch-instance-using-python