# query elasticsearch from python

Tags: python, database, elasticsearch

I need to query elastic database with Python. I want to analyze data from elastic in jupyter notebook. I am connected to Elastic but i don't know how to call the elastic API. I don't know where I can find the URL of the database I want to query.
Does someone know where I can find the url ? Thanks

Comment: It all depends where your elasticsearch is installed. It could be any cloud provider. A good starting point is to check out https://www.instaclustr.com/support/documentation/elasticsearch/using-elasticsearch/connecting-to-elasticsearch-with-python/  which was the first thing i found when I googled 'python connect to elasticsearch'.

Comment: elasticsearch is on an aws cluster. I am already connected to the cluster. I just don't know where I can find the path of the database.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528839/connecting-to-aws-elasticsearch-instance-using-python#:~:text=This%20is%20the%20correct%20way%20to%20connect%20to,doesn%27t%20have%20the%20host%20nor%20the%20port%20parameters.  You can use curl/postman to test if you can request or post data to it.