# Connect to aws opensearch with master user by python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opensearch

I've created an OpenSearch domain like in this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/gsgcreate-domain.html). But I am confused that I can't connect to it. I've tried many things and don't know which was closer to the solution. So could you please give me a link for a guide on how to create a domain and connect to it or how to connect if [that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/gsgcreate-domain.html) guide is ok?

Comment: What do you mean by not connecting to it. Show logs etc or elaborate on the issue you are facing. Have you created the domain in private or public subnet?

Comment: @Riz  I created the domain in a public subnet, all settings like in the provided link.  I've tried code from this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528839/connecting-to-aws-elasticsearch-instance-using-python   but there they didn't use master user I supposed

Comment: I would suggest to designate an IAM user as master user, give https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ac.html#es-ac-types-resource resrouce based policy to the domain and then save the credentials of the IAM user (better named) and then you only need `credentials = boto3.Session(profile_name='yourmasteruser').get_credentials()`. Everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ingest data into the opensearch domain as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/gsgupload-data.html).
Then search for the inserted data as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/gsgsearch.html)

You can also use any Postman or a simple python code file with a Get request to the domain endpoint.

P.S: Don't have enough reputation to post a comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).